# MongoDB and Python - Dictionary with Lists

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo, database

How would you obtain a list from within a dictionary after you insert it into MongoDB?

For example, say I have this entry stored in a collection:

`{'Store': 'Store A','Brands':['Nike','Adidas','Reebok']}`

How do I access "Store A" and print just the list of brands?

I would like to just print the values in the list:

`Nike
Adidas
Reebok`

I'm just trying to learn how to use MongoDB and can't seem to find a similar example in their documentation. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you inserted using something like the `db.insert()` method, the following should work:

```
for brand in db.find_one({"Store":"Store A"})["Brands"]:
  print(brand)
```

When you use pymongo's `find_one()` method, you will get a dictionary object (if an object is found) which you can index as `["Brand"]` and have an array of the brands.

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly how I wanted! I had a follow-up question. Would this syntax be the same if I had to store a list within the key `Brand` by using the `insert_one()` method?

Comment: Yes, it should be.